# Chart js additional label data

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I'm creating chart with *chart.js* plugin.
I need to put one more parameter (*additional data*) for each of chart elements in tooltip beetween label and value. However i can't find information how to do it. Tooltip only with label and value works fine.

Code for setting tooltip is pretty simple:

```
tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%>  <%= value %>"});
```

I wish to add my data for each parameter lets say like this:

```
        tooltipTemplate: 
"<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%> <%= value %> My parameter: <%= additionalData%>"
```

I tried to send this *additionalData* in many ways and cant't figure it out.

I don't need to show *additionalData* in chart, only in tooltip.

Is there a way to do it according to *chart.js* documentation?

Comment: What kind of *additional data* do you want to add ? Is it the same thing to all the labels (like adding `"$"` after the label) ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: From what I remember, I didn't. I rearranged the way data is displayed.